# how to sort nested array in laravel collection

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to sort nested collection but i can't get correct results.

category tags collection

```json
[
 {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Age",
        "tags": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "18+"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "21+"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "25+"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "30+"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "17+"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "16+"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "26+"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "13+"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "24+"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "20+"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "19+"
            }
        ],
}
]
```

i'm trying to sort tags:

```php
<?php

$categoryTagsSorted = $categoryTags->transform(
    function ($categoryTag) {
        $sortedTags = $categoryTag->tags->sortBy('name');

        // $sortedTags->values() return correct sorted array
        $categoryTag->tags = $sortedTags->values();// < - this not work
        return $categoryTag;
    }
);
```

`$categoryTagsSorted` returns untouched results, but when i assign `$sortedTags`
to `$categoryTag->newField = $sortedTags->values()` i've got sorted tags in `newField`.

Question is how to return collection with sorted tags?

Comment: Could you provide some output examples on what you expect to get?

Answer (score 1):

In your code I believe you have misunderstood the use of the `transform()` method. It is used to iterate over each item in the collection and replaces the item with the value you give it in the callback. In your code you have also simply returned the original value without applying any 'transformation' to it. If you wish to alter the value of tags on the object you could try reassigning the object property:

```php
$categoryTags->tags = $categoryTags->tags->sortBy('name');
```

Read the docs on the `transform` method here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-transform#

## Update

I think you can simply use [`map`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-map) and re-assign the tags property to accomplish the solution:

```php
$categoryTags->map(function($categoryTag) {
    $categoryTag->tags = $categoryTag->tags->sortBy('name');
    return $categoryTag;
});
```

The following test code worked OK for me...

```php
$categoryTags = collect([
    (object) [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Age',
        'tags' => collect([
            ['id' => 1, 'name' => '18+'],
            ['id' => 2, 'name' => '21+'],
            ['id' => 3, 'name' => "25+"],
            ['id' => 4, 'name' => "30+"],
            ['id' => 5, 'name' => "17+"]
        ])
    ]
]);

$categoryTags->map(function($categoryTag) {
    $categoryTag->tags = $categoryTag->tags->sortBy('name');
    return $categoryTag;
});

var_dump($categoryTags);
```

Output:

```php
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#1029 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#1030 (3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "Age"
      ["tags"]=>
      object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#1026 (1) {
        ["items":protected]=>
        array(5) {
          [4]=>
          array(2) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(5)
            ["name"]=>
            string(3) "17+"
          }
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(1)
            ["name"]=>
            string(3) "18+"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(2) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(2)
            ["name"]=>
            string(3) "21+"
          }
          [2]=>
          array(2) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(3)
            ["name"]=>
            string(3) "25+"
          }
          [3]=>
          array(2) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(4)
            ["name"]=>
            string(3) "30+"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
=> null
```

Try it out here: https://web.tinkerwell.app/#/snippets/e2c93c20-5706-4ffd-bcc0-601aae861c8b (takes a min to load)

Comment: It doesn't work either.
It returns sorted tags without parent category tag

Comment: @burasuk I've updated the solution using map() and given an example of it working, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
$categoryTagsSorted = $categoryTags->each(
    function ($categoryTag) {
        $categoryTag = $categoryTag->tags->sortBy('name');
    }
);
```

Comment: it returns sorted tags but without parent category tag